# What is the proper syntax in C++ for template classes with pointer template types with reference variables?

Tags: c++, pointers

If I have a template class like this:

```
template <class T>
class MyClass
{
    public:
    virtual void MyFunction(const T& t)
    {
        ///
    }
};
```

How will MyFunction look like in a concrete class with a pointer T?

```
class Data;
class MyDerivedClass : public MyClass<Data*>
{
    public:
    void MyFunction(???) override
    {
        ///
    }
};
```

Also, how should I use the variable?

Comment: Why would you derive from the template class? Just use it.

Comment: `Data* const &t` will work.

Comment: A side note: this shows the advantage of using east-const. If you used the east-const equivalent: `T const & t` you could just replace `T` with `Data*`, getting the proper: `Data* const &t`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really want this setup, you can.

Example:

```cpp
class MyDerivedClass : public MyClass<Data*> {
public:
    using value_type = Data*;   // alias to simplify overriding

    void MyFunction(const value_type& dpr) override {
        // ....
    }
};
```

> how should I use the variable?

You'd use it like any other pointer. Note that it's not the `Data` instance that is `const`, it's the pointer itself.

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
void MyFunction(Data * const & i) override
```

But also consider using the template instead of a derived class.